# I can't print select query in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new in Yii. I can't print select query in Yii.

If in the case PHP, we can print a query like:

```
echo $qu = "select * from news".This print result is  like 'select * from news'.
```

Can I print this query like in this way?

```
$model=Job_apply::model()->findAll(array(
    'select'=>'*',
    "condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
    "condition"=>"job_id=$job_id"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo the query like that with Yii. What you can do is enable the logging on queries. You do this by adding/changing a few settings in your `config/main.php`. This will put the executed sql query at the bottom of every page.

Add `enableParamLogging` to your db section.

```
'db'=>array(
    // .. other options
   enableParamLogging' => true,
),
```

And make sure you have the following `'log'` settings. The routes array can also contain other logroutes.

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array( 
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace,log',
            'categories' => 'system.db.CDbCommand',
            'logFile' => 'db.log',
        ), 
    ),
),
```

Comment: I dont see config.php file in yii ,i think you are saying main.php in config folder?